# N-grams based on POS tags : Spacy

Tags: spacy, n-gram, pos-tagger, chunking

I have a list of 20 rules to extract spacy tri-grams chunks from a sentence.

Chunks can be of pos-tags trigrams:-

- Rule 1: [VERB,ADJ,NOUN]
- Rule 2: [NOUN,VERB, ADV]
- Rule 3: [NOUN,ADP,NOUN]  etc.

Example Input:

```
"Education of children was our revenue earning secondary business."
```

Desired Output:

```
["Education of children","earning secondary business"]
```

I have already tried spacy Matcher and need something more optimised than running a for loop as the dataset is very large.

Comment: Are you already using [rule based matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching)?

Comment: Have you managed to identify which part of your code is too slow? Maybe if you post what you have so far it will help

Comment: Added the detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [rule-based matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching). Your code will look something like:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

list_of_rules = [
    ["VERB", "ADJ", "NOUN"],
    ["NOUN", "VERB", "ADV"],
    ["NOUN", "ADP", "NOUN"],
    # more rules here...
]

rules = [[{"POS": i} for i in j] for j in list_of_rules]

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("rules", None, *rules)

doc = nlp("Education of children was our revenue earning secondary business.")
matches = matcher(doc)
print([doc[start:end].text for _, start, end in matches])
```

which will print

```
['Education of children', 'earning secondary business']
```

Comment: Already tried this, i need something more optimised as the data is very large.

Comment: @hawk ok great. Please add as much detail as possible to your question. At the moment is says nothing about what you've tried or that you need an optimised solution.